# Set ListView checkmark as checked/unchecked by program in Android ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

Couples of example I have had referred for my Android application. In ListActivity,before the **OnCreate** method, the **items** array was predefined as

```
String[] items = new String[]{"Text for Item1", "text for item2", ....};
```

Inside the **OnCreate** method, I use the simplest way to set the adapter and display the list view below:

```
setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items));
```

And I have had override the method:

```
@Override    
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)    
{     
     CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)v;
     textview.setChecked(!textview.isChecked());
}
```

All above code is worked fine. The checkmark for each litem in the ListView can be displayed and set checked/unchecked manually.

**MY PROBLEM IS**: 
I want to set some items by program,not by hand clicking, to be checked/unchecked and the checkmark be changed along too. Can it be done and how to do it ?

Thanks for the help in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think Romain Guy who is Android Engineer at Google said in [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/zPSHPEHtu94/NRYS5iYyPsUJ) can resolve your prolbem:

```
Actually you want to use CheckedTextView with choiceMode. That's what
CheckedTextView is for. However, you should not be calling setChecked
from bindView(), but let ListView handle it. The problem was that you
were doing ListView's job a second time. You don't need listeners
(click on onlistitem), calls to setChecked, etc.
```

Here is my solution for this:

```java
class MyActivity extends ListActivity { // or ListFragment

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // some initialize

        new UpdateCheckedTask().execute(); // call after setListAdapter
    }

    // some implementation

    class UpdateChecked extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Integer>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Integer> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getListAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                return null;
            }

            List<Integer> positionList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int position = 0; position < listAdapter.getCount(); position++) {
                Item item = (Cursor) listAdapter.getItem(position); // or cursor, depends on your ListAdapter implementaiton
                boolean checked = item.isChecked() // your model
                positionList.add(position, checked);
            }
            return positionList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Integer> result) { // setItemChecked in UI thread
            if (result == null) {
                return;
            }

            ListView listView = getListView();
            for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = result.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Integer position = iterator.next();
                listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gasol ! Howover I can not follow the solution. Since the method setListAdapter() I used  on ListView is the simplest way. To change to use setItemChecked() mehtod in AbsListView widget provided, may let my application more complicated. Is it the only way ?

Comment: @cmh There is no way to do this in ListAdapter, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Gasol ! And will try the soulution later and see if it can meet the  expectation.